# Keep SWF on the bottom when Lighbox dims the background

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash, lightbox

I am running a Wordpress-based website which has a SWF ad banner in the sidebar. At the same time, I'm using Lightbox for displaying the images and dimming the rest of the content. However, the SWF banner remains, so to speak, at the same layer as the lightbox popup and is not dimmed.

What properties should I set for said banner if I want it to play nicely with the lightbox effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see wmode="transparent" in your embed code change it to wmode="opaque" this will resolve the overlapping of swf object.

Here is some weak [adobe documentation](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) on different flash 9 wmode settings.

A note of caution on wmode transparent is here in the [adobe bug trac](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-892).

And new for flash 10, are two new wmodes: gpu and direct. Please refer to [Adobe Knowledge Base about wmode](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values/fplayer10.1_hardware_acceleration_04.html).